# How to use an HTML partial from within Coffeescript function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

In a Rails app I have a Coffeescript function that, amongst other things, renders some HTML and adds it to the DOM.

```
# inject.js.coffee
(($) ->
  # some actions
  html_string = '<div><p>My complex HTML</p></div>'
  inject_node[0].innerHTML += html_string
```

This HTML is also coded in a partial and used elsewhere.

```
# model/_inject.html.erb
  <div><p>My complex HTML</p></div>
```

Is there a way to DRY this code by calling the partial from the coffeescript?

This event is not passing through a controller action, so I don't think `action.js` partials will work in this case.

One approach I have explored is to render the partial as a string within a data attribute, and pass this to the coffeescript

which returns

```
undefined method `render_as_string' for #<#<Class:0x007fbd4b633d68>:0x007fbd4b617f50>
```

I also tried

```
<%= content_tag :div, id: "partial", data: { partial: escape_javascript(render( partial: 'model/inject' )).to_s } do %>
<% end %>
```

But this is rendering the partial, not displaying as a data attribute.

Is there a way to use a partial from within coffeescript, without duplicating the rendered HTML?

As background, I am implementing [blueimp gallery](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery) and I want to add an [additional gallery element](https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery#additional-gallery-elements). This element is described in the `_inject.html.erb' partial.

The page contains something like the following:

```
<div id="links">
    <a href="images/banana.jpg" title="Banana" data-partial="This is where I want to render a partial as text">Banana</a>
    <a href="images/apple.jpg" title="Apple" data-description="This is where I want to render a partial as text">Apple</a>
</div>
```

Clicking an image link calls the following function

```
blueimp.Gallery(
    document.getElementById('links'),
    {
        onslide: function (index, slide) {
            var partial = this.list[index].getAttribute('data-partial'),
                node    = this.container.find('.partial');
            node.empty();
            if (partial) {
                node[0].innerHTML += partial;
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Which displays the following blind

```
<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery">
    <div class="slides"></div>
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <!-- The placeholder for the description label: -->
    <div class="partial"></div>
    <a class="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="next">›</a>
    <a class="close">×</a>
    <a class="play-pause"></a>
    <ol class="indicator"></ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best approach would be to go through the controller. If this does not suite you, let me know and I'll propose another solution that would work without extra requests.

The ideal way for this would be to initiate an ajax request that would render a partial in a `js.erb` and send it within the response as js. You could then write you DOM insertion logic in that `js.erb` which would be executed in your browser when it is received as response.

```
$('selector').html("<%= j render partial: 'model/inject' %>");
```

In order to tell your controller to send the response as js, you must add a new action and route for your ajax call and write the following in your action:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js
end
```

This will look for your action_name.js.erb file in your contoller's views directory. You can send the ajax call from your coffe like this:

```
$.ajax
    url: '/controllers/action'
    dataType: 'script'
```

**Updated answer**

Looking at the updated code, I would suggest that you render your partial in a separate `div` instead of within a `data` attribute for an element.

```
<div id="hidden_div" class="hidden">
    <%= render partial: 'model/inject' %>
</div>
```

The browser will consider the partial text to be html once it is received in the response as the content contains non-encoded html characters.

Rendering this partial in a **hidden** div and then selecting it as follows would likely work:

```
html_to_be_inserted = $('#hidden_div').html()
```

**Another Option**

You may also try this to escape the html characters while rendering the partial in the `data` attribute:

```
<%=h render partial: 'model/inject' %>
```

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: thanks @jawad, I can't see an obvious way to combine blueimp gallery with ajax requests, without a major rewrite of the gallery code. Perhaps I am missing something obvious however. I've included more of the gallery code to my question. Grateful for your thoughts how to achieve this with ajax, or without going through the controller

Comment: @AndyHarvey, I updated my answer accordingly. Check it out.

Comment: thanks @jawad, add `h` did escape the HTML and enable me to add it to the data attribute. But, as I thought more about this problem, I realized that you were indeed correct the first time, and that it is better to go through the controller. One of the main reasons I was using blueimp gallery was to create a lightbox effect. This is fairly trivial to implement via a JS controller that appends the lightbox markup to the DOM, and removes the overhead of an additional jquery plugin. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of help @AndyHarvey!